# How to customise Eclipse for my own language?

Tags: eclipse

I have made a simple experimental language of my own. I want make Eclipse editor plugins or whatever I need to edit the programs for my language.

How do I begin with writing an Eclipse feature for my language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about trying Eclipse **[Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**?
(That is if your language can follow an [EBNF grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form))

> Xtext is a framework for development of textual domain specific languages (DSLs).
>   **Just describe your very own DSL using Xtext's simple EBNF grammar language and the generator will create a parser, an AST-meta model (implemented in EMF) as well as a full-featured Eclipse text editor from that**.

[alt text http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/images/screenshot-title.png](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/images/screenshot-title.png)

> The Framework integrates with technology from Eclipse Modeling such as EMF, GMF, M2T and parts of EMFT.
>   Development with Xtext is optimized for short turn-arounds, so that adding new features to an existing DSL is a matter of minutes. Still sophisticated programming languages can be implemented.